# How to kill a twisted websocket server programmatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, twisted, autobahn

How do you kill a websocket server programmatically?  I'll be deploying this server to production along side other things.  And I like to build a single python script that sends a kill signal to everything.  I cannot figure out how to kill this thing without a user keyboard interrupt or a kill -9.

sys.exit() didn't work.

psutil and terminate() didn't work either

```
import os
import psutil

current_system_pid = os.getpid()

ThisSystem = psutil.Process(current_system_pid)
ThisSystem.terminate()
```

I'm out of ideas.  For now I'm killing it on the command line with kill -9.

When I kill it varous ways, it tend to see this message below, but the scrip is still running

```
2020-12-12 12:24:54-0500 [autobahn.twisted.websocket.WebSocketServerFactory] (TCP Port 8080 Closed)
2020-12-12 12:24:54-0500 [-] Stopping factory <autobahn.twisted.websocket.WebSocketServerFactory object at 0x110680f28>
```

**autobahn install**:

```
pip install autobahn[twisted]
```

**Code:**

```
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, WebSocketServerFactory
import sys
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.internet import reactor

class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    def onConnect(self, request):
        print("Client connecting: {0}".format(request.peer))

    def onOpen(self):
        print("WebSocket connection open.")

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        print("Text message received: {0}".format(payload.decode('utf8')))

        # echo back message verbatim
        # self.sendMessage(payload, isBinary)

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        print("WebSocket connection closed: {0}".format(reason))


def StopWebsocketServer():
    PrintAndLog_FuncNameHeader("Begin")
    reactor.stop()
    PrintAndLog_FuncNameHeader("End")


if __name__ == '__main__':   
    # TODO remove the logging that came in the example
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

    factory = WebSocketServerFactory("ws://127.0.0.1:8080")
    factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol

    # note to self: if using putChild, the child must be bytes...
    reactor.listenTCP(Port_ws, factory)
    reactor.run()
```

**Solution** using @Jean-Paul Calderone's answer:

```
    import os
    import signal
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGKILL)
```

I have an external python script that sends a kill signal to each of my python scripts.  The kill signal is simply the existence of a file that every script knows to look for.  Once that kill signal appears, each script knows it has x seconds before it will be killed.  This way they have a few seconds to gracefully finish something.

Comment: Have you considered [`os.kill()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill)?

Comment: os.kill did indeed work with the signal.SIGKILL. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`twisted.internet.reactor.stop()` is how you cause the reactor to shut down.  This is usually what results in a Twisted-based program exiting (though of course it doesn't necessarily have to, if the program does more things after the reactor shuts down - but this is uncommon).

However, it sounds like you don't want to know what Python code to run inside the process to end it.  You want to know what some *other* process can *do* to your Twisted-based process to make it exit.  You gave two solutions - KeyboardInterrupt and SIGKILL.  You didn't mention why either of these two solutions is inappropriate.  They seem fine to me.

If you're uncomfortable with SIGKILL (which you shouldn't be, after all, your program might meet an untimely demise for many reasons and you should be prepared to deal with this) then what you might have overlooked about KeyboardInterrupt is that it is merely the exception that is raised inside a Python program by the default SIGINT handler.

If you send SIGINT to a Twisted-based process then, under normal usage, this will stop the reactor and allow an orderly shutdown.

Comment: `signal.SIGKILL` worked perfectly.  Thanks.  I did try reactor.stop() and for some reason it was stopping the websocket server but not exiting the script.  It was acting as if it was still stuck in a loop but I didn't have any loops anywhere.  It's possible I was doing something wrong there, but SIGKILL is doing exactly what I want so I'll go with it.